# Java reading a file of numbers and printing them out

Tags: java

I have this code

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("hello.txt");
   while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
       int i = scanner.nextInt();
       System.out.println(i);
    }
```

the data values I have in a hello.txt are

1 2 3 22 33 123

but when I run the program there is no output.
Is there something I am not using / line of code??

Answer (score 5):

The `Scanner` constructor you are using takes a string *from which to read values*. It's not a filename. There are no integers in the string `hello.txt` so you get no output.

If you want to read from the file called `hello.txt`, try

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("hello.txt"));
```

Comment: Do I need to give the full file path e.g. "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\vm\hello.txt" Then it gives an error "Illegal Escape Character" .   If I just say "hello.txt" when i run it It says it cannot locate it in java.io.fileinputstream. Is there a way to specify the full file path

Comment: You don't need to give the full file path: you could supply a path that's relative to the current working directory of the program. You need to escape backslashes, e.g. `C:\\Users...` or you could use forward slashes, e.g. `C:/Users...`.

Comment: For more info about specifying a filename when using the `File` class, see the Javadoc for that class: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: I Tried the forward slash so it reads like this         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/vm/hello.txt")); But I get an error when I run it says file not found (The system cannot find the files specificed) (in java.io.fileinputstream)

Comment: I looked at the link and asm still getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("hello.txt"));
```